# Downloaded font not showing colors, only shape / contour

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, web-fonts

I've downloaded a couple of fonts - Abelone and Playbox, but neither of the font colors or designs are showing up in Illustrator. They are just showing in all black/solid colors:

[image: screenshot of Adobe Illustrator]

They should show the colors as in the original designs:

[image: screenshot of the font Playbox]

[image: screenshot of the font Abelone]

I found the fonts on https://colorfontweek.fontself.com/2018#playbox. Any idea why the colors aren't showing up?

Comment: You should add your Illustrator version at the question, the selling site says clearly the fonts are for CC2018+.

Comment: Ah - I have 2017 - let me update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Adobe 2019 fixed the problem.